# Save the results of a dark mode function as a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have everything working to toggle between light/dark mode, i just cant seem to figure out how to get the results of the js function to save as a cookie between pages and reloads. I have looked everywhere and just cannot find the proper way to phrase it. I always seem to either have a cookie saved, or the function executes without a cookie. Just cant get both to work. Here is what I have so far.
HTML:

```
        <button class="dark-mode" id="theme" onclick="togTheme()">Dark Mode</button>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --navHeight: 70px;
  --darkHue: #B0BEC5;
  --darkShade: #37474F;
  --lightShade: #455A64;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --hue: #ECEFF1;
  --shade: #263238;
  --black: #222222;
  --gray: #eee;
  --blue: #0071BC
}

.light-theme {
  --themeDropDownBg: var(--goldCrayola);
  --themeIconBorderColor: var(--sage);
  --navBg: var(--hue);
  --navLinkHoverBg: var(--darkHue);
  --mainBg: var(--white);
  --fontColor: var(--black);
}

.dark-theme {
  --themeDropDownBg: var(--msuGreen);
  --themeIconBorderColor: var(--richBlackForeground);
  --navBg: var(--lightShade);
  --navLinkHoverBg: var(--darkShade);
  --mainBg: var(--shade);
  --fontColor: var(--hue);
}



* {
  color: var(--fontColor);
  font-family: 'Risque';
  transition: background 500ms ease,
    padding 500ms linear;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: var(--mainBg);
}

nav {
  background: var(--navBg);
  color: var(--fontColor);
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: var(--navLinkHoverBg);
  color: var(--blue);
}

nav button {
  background: var(--navBg);
  color: var(--fontColor);
}

nav button:hover {
  background-color: var(--navLinkHoverBg);
  color: var(--blue);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function togTheme() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
  var x = document.getElementById("theme");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Dark Mode") {
    x.innerHTML = "Light Mode";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like something you'd want to use [Local storage for, not cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220802/12101554)

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
const setCookie = (name, value, exdays) => {
    const d = new Date(); // Gets current date
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000)); //calculates the date when it has to expire
    const expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/"; // sets the cookie
}
```

With this function you can easily add a cookie. Give the type of mode in as a value and the amount of days till the cookie has to expire and the name of the cookie.

For toggling between themes I would personally use localstorage or save the mode in your backend database.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind explaining how i would save it to local storage?

Comment: I think this link can explain it better than me ;) 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: I had gone over that page already and it hasn't helped me...

Comment: const togTheme = () => {
  const theme = localstorage.getItem(''theme);
  if(!theme) {localstorage.setItem('theme', 'Light')}
  const element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
  const x = document.getElementById("theme");
  if (theme === "Dark") {
    localstorage.setItem('theme', 'Light');
    x.innerHTML = "Light Mode";
  } else {
    localstorage.setItem('theme', 'Dark');
    x.innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
  }